# Merge Observables of UIBarButtonItem tap and UIView tapGesture()

Tags: ios, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have two sources for the same action. A regular RxCocoa tap in a `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
browseButton.rx.tap
```

and a RxGesture tap gesture recognizer in a `UIView`:

```
notConnectedView.rx.tapGesture().when(.recognized)
```

I subscribe to it the usual way:

```
<any_of_the_observables>
    .subscribe(onNext: {
        // Do things
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

This works with both observables, and now I want to merge it but cannot achieve it. As they are two observables of different events `merge` does not work.

```
Observable.of(notConnectedView.rx.tapGesture().when(.recognized), browseButton.rx.tap)
```

> Type 'inout UIView' does not conform to protocol 'ReactiveCompatible'

Is it possible to make this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get same events type, for example convert both events to void:

```
let buttonItemTap = item.rx.tap.map { _ in return () }
let viewTap: Observable<Void> = v.rx.tapGesture().when(.recognized).map { _ in return () }

Observable.of(buttonItemTap, viewTap).merge()
    .subscribe(onNext: { (_) in
        print("tapped")
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Worked :D Thanks!